# How connect SciChart to Nuxt

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, scichart.js

I need how coonect SciChart to Nuxt.js
i did

> npm init nuxt-app "scichart"
> npm install scichart
> and i catch error

packeg.json

```
{
  "name": "scichart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "buildsci": "webpack",
    "startsci": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.15.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.7",
    "scichart": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.3.2",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0 ",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: npm i
npm run dev

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: yesteday. SciChart support just did for my example
https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.JS.Examples/tree/master/Sandbox/demo-nuxtjs

Answer (score 1):

There are now a number of samples on the SciChart.js Github showing how to setup SciChart in frameworks. These include:

- [Next.js](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.JS.Examples/tree/master/Sandbox/demo-nextjs)
- [Nuxt.js](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.JS.Examples/tree/master/Sandbox/demo-nuxtjs)
- [React](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.JS.Examples/tree/master/Sandbox/demo-react-scichart)
- [Vue.js](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.JS.Examples/tree/master/Sandbox/demo-vue-scichart)
- [Blazor](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.JS.Examples/tree/master/Sandbox/demo-blazor)
- [Angular](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.JS.Examples/tree/master/Sandbox/demo-angular-scichart)
- [Just Javascript (no framework)](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.JS.Examples/tree/master/Sandbox/demo-browser-global-module)

Plus many more. The common problem with these frameworks is loading WebAssembly. SciChart.js uses WebAssembly to achieve really high performance 2D & 3D charts & graphs. Wasm file needs to be in the output folder when your project is built. This is different for every framework.

There is now a page on the [SciChart.js Documentation](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/js/current/SciChart_JS_User_Manual.html) showing how to load webassembly flawlessly without requiring Webpack or Copy plugins in package.json.

See the how-to article here: [Creating a new SciChartSurface and loading Wasm](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/js/current/SciChartSurface.create.html)

> **Deploying Wasm (WebAssembly) and Data Files with your app**
>
> If you receive an error message when running your app, you may not
> have deployed the Wasm (WebAssembly) or data files correctly. Below
> are some steps on how to resolve that.
>
> *Error: Could not load SciChart WebAssembly module. Check your build*
> *process and ensure that your scichart2d.wasm, scichart2d.data and*
> *scichart2d.js files are from the same version*
>
> Option 1: Package Wasm & Data Files with WebPack (or similar)
> ...
>
> Option 2: Load Wasm from URL with SciChartSurface.configure() or
> useWasmFromCDN()
> ...
>
> We've packaged a helpful function that
> automatically loads the latest & correct version of SciChart's Wasm &
> Data files from CDN.
>
> To use this, instead of calling
> SciChartSurface.configure() passing in a URL, call
> SciChartSurface.useWasmFromCDN().
>
> ```
> import {SciChartSurface} from "scichart/Charting/Visuals/SciChartSurface";
>
> export async function initSciChart() {
>     // Call this once before any SciChartSurface is shown.
>     // This is equivalent to calling SciChartSurface.configure() with the CDN URL (JSDelivr)
>     SciChartSurface.useWasmFromCDN();
> }
> ```